# STM32F103 USB HID

Tags: usb, hid, stm32

I'm trying to connect my board to pc with no success.

Here is what i tried;
I tried "STM32 FS Device Lib". It includes an example project named Custom HID. But it also uses some leds, some EXTIs and a pin named USB_DISCONNECT. I ported the code, removed the USB_DISCONNECT part and the leds. When i called USB_init(), nothing happens. No device found by the pc.

There is no need to configure custom endpoints, descriptor or anything else. Just communication for personal use. I want simply call functions i.e. USB_read() and USB_write().

Is there any simple library or example project that i can use?

Comment: This question post lacks information on the code which showed the problem. Furthermore, an unfocussed question for suggestions on USB library running on STM32 is too open and deprecated on StackOverflow as far as I see.